# R hangs while plotting on RHEL5

Tags: r, linux, plot, ggplot2, rhel

Any plotting package is hanging, even for very simple plots. Here is my sample code:

```
user.desktop% R

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = (1:10)^2)
> plot(d$x, d$y)
```

The window hangs from here until I terminate the session. The code works fine on Windows 3.2.2. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

### Update:

Reconstructed output from `capabilites()` from comments:

```
> data.frame(capabilities())
capabilities..
jpeg                  TRUE
png                   TRUE
tiff                  TRUE
tcltk                 TRUE
X11                   TRUE
aqua                  FALSE
http/ftp              TRUE
sockets               TRUE
libxml                TRUE
fifo                  TRUE
cledit                TRUE
iconv                 TRUE
NLS                   TRUE
profmem               FALSE
cairo                 TRUE
ICU                   FALSE
long.double           TRUE
libcurl               FALSE
```

Comment: If you run `capabilities()` what is the output?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to format a code block in comments, but here is the output: > capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl
       TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE

Comment: The way you format it in comments is to... don't. Just put that info in the original question at the end.  It's relevant info for everybody and you don't want them to have to dig around in the comments to see it right?

Comment: Thanks. Any further thoughts on what's going wrong?